# Using Visual C++ String Variables As Object

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli, managed-c++

I am just learning C++ and slowly getting the hang of it after such a shock from working with HTML, CSS and Javascript to a completely new way of writing code which I still don't really understand. But I have been able to make a web browser program.

Now I've been needing the use of variables, and after some Googling have worked out how to use strings (or at least a way to get them working for me) like so:

```
#include <string>
namespace Browser1 {
      using namespace std;
...
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
      String^ var = "label1";
      String^ var2 = "hello world";
      var->Text = var2;
}
```

But then I get these errors saying that the `Text` is an ambiguous symbol. I am almost certain this is because I have used the variable as the object but why?

Comment: Please format your code by indenting it with four spaces.

Comment: Please also note that this is "Managed C++", not the same as "C++".

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal : Actually, this is C++/CLI, not Managed C++; Managed Extensions for C++ was a set of compiler keywords added to C++ that came with VC++ 7.0 and 7.1, whereas C++/CLI is an entirely different language (as you note).

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal : You're one of my favorite posters in terms of having pedantically correct answers, so I figured it was worth clarifying ;-]

Answer (score 0):

Which object would you think is typed as Object that causes this?

Afaict your problem is

```
      var->Text = var2;
```

which is rubbish, because `var` is declared as `String^` (2 lines up) so it can't have the Text property. Surely, you were intending to use another variable? (Such as sender?)

Comment: but i defined var as "label1" 2 lines up so the text is a property of label1 or have i completely lost the plot?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid you have. `String^ var = "label1"` assigns the **value** "label1" to a **variable** named `var` which is declared of **type** `String^` (note the three bolded words: **type**, **variable** and **value**). So, it _is-a_ String, not posessing a property named `Text`. If you wanted to assign "Hello world" text to some label named label1, you'd need to write something more like `label1->Text = "Hello world"`. Not having windows/your code I cannot make a more reliable example for you right now